# How can I copy a table from one database to another on the same server without shell (command line) access?

Tags: mysql, linux, joomla, cpanel, whm

I do not use the Shell interface.
I have my own shared Linux server at SoftLayer with WHM and CPanel for my two joomla website installations.

I would like to start migrating populated tables from the old site to the new one.
BUT I don't know how to use shell access, and I prefer a graphical interface anyway. 
I am working on installed extensions one at a time.

I saw a mention about MySQL Workbench 6.0.7
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/
but am unsure of it's operation on my server.

Any insight on making this task easier or more foolproof would be appreciated.

Comment: if you have CPanel then you should probably also have phpMyAdmin, which is a nice and easy mysql web interface. Login to CPanel and look for it. There are easy to use wizards for exporting and importing the databases and/or tables

Comment: Have you tried looking at Joomla's documentation regarding migration?  This page talks about using phpMyAdmin: http://docs.joomla.org/Copying_a_Joomla_website

Answer (score 0):

Export your tables from PHPMyAdmin on your cpanel, then import them to your new server via PHPMyAdmin too.